# Expressions in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have a persistent class Item with a quantity field and a price field.
Is there a way to build a Criteria that calculates the sum of quantity*price?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can also use an SQL projection. It should be something like:

```
session.createCriteria(Item.class) 
        .createAlias("item", "i") 
        .setProjection( Projections.projectionList() 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.id") ) 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.price") ) 
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("i.quantity") ) 
            .add( Projections.sqlProjection( 
                    "price * quantity as total", 
                    new String[] { "total" }, 
                    new Type[] { Hibernate.DOUBLE } 
                  ) 
            ) 
        );
```

Ori

Comment: Can you please tell where is the function that creates the total? This only creates the product.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but you can use "derived properties" to get something rather similar.

For example, you can map a totalPrice property to an SQL expression:

```
<property name="totalPrice" formula="quantity * price" type="big_decimal"/>
```

The SQL formula "quantity * price" is evaluated every time the entity is retrieved from the database.

Ori

The Hibernate [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html) contain more info about this.

Answer (score 1):

It is (probably) not possible to do it with Criteria. But [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) can be helpful for this.

```
SELECT ent.quantity*ent.price from EntityName as ent WHERE ent.id = ?
```

Comment: Much better with HQL