# Using Hibernate and Criteria to Select the Most Common Value

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Given a table, say:

```
orderId | typeId
----------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 2
4       | 5
5       | 1
6       | 2
```

And I have an `Order` object which has a `Type` object (`Type` has a `Set` of `Order`s in the other direction.

How would I go about retrieving the most popular `Type` of `Order` (in this case, type 1) using Hibernate's Criteria API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might wanna look into [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection). You should be able to use [Projections.groupProperty()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) on the "type" association, and add up the results.
check this SO question: [Expressions in hibernate criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961480/expressions-in-hibernate-criteria)

**edit:** tried it and the following seems to work fine:

Order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Type type;
}
```

Type:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_types")
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}
```

and the Criteria:

```
    Criteria c=sess.createCriteria(Order.class)
        .createCriteria("type")
        .setProjection(
                Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))
                .add(Projections.rowCount(),"rowcount")
        )
        .addOrder(org.hibernate.criterion.Order.desc("rowcount"));

    for (Object[] result:(List<Object[]>) c.list()){
        System.out.println("type id: " + result[0] + "\tcount: " + result[1]);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I misworded my question. An `Order` has a many-to-one relationship with `Type`.

Comment: i changed the answer to reflect that, but the criteria is almost the same ;)

Comment: Beauty. I was able to figure it out on my own with what you had but thought you may want to update your answer :)

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me. I had to do it this way to get it to work: `Criteria c = sess.createCriteria(Type.class);  c.createCriteria("orders");` Does that make sense to you?

Comment: it seems you have a one-to-many from type to orders and not a many-to-one from order to types. thats why you have a property "orders" on your Type class. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584521/in-a-bidirectional-jpa-onetomany-manytoone-association-what-is-meant-by-the-inv

Comment: Yes, that is correct (my relationships are identical to what's asked in that question [which spelled things out nicely, btw. Thanks]). Should it not be that way?

Comment: the difference is a one-to-many association needs a jointable since one record in the type table cant hold n orders. but a many-to-one relationship can be built upon just one foreign key in the order record. id say it depends on the use-case which way to go, although i prefer many-to-one because of the lower complexity

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the documentation of the Hibernate Criteria API, could you do something like this:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Order.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.rowCount(),"rCount")
        .add( Projections.groupProperty("typeId") )
    )
    .addOrder(Order.desc("rCount") )
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .list();
```

This may need modified to work with the proper classes

Comment: if Type is an associated class you will have to create a Criteria on that association first to access it's ids. something like `createCriteria(Order.class).createCriteria("types");`

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-worded my question. Revised.